# Custom log4net azure blob appender stops logging when a file reaches 5.4MB

Tags: c#, log4net, azure-blob-storage

I am using the appender below to pipe our log messages to Azure with Log4Net.
Everything works fine, until the blob file reaches the size of 5.4MB. From than, no logs are appended to the log file anymore.

What is causing this? And how can I solve this?

```
namespace Digicreate.Core.Infrastructure.Logging
{
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Core;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

// ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
// justification: used in log4net configuration file
public class AzureBlobTxtFileAppender : BufferingAppenderSkeleton
{
    private CloudStorageAccount _account;
  ...removed unimportant code...

            protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        var appendBlobReference = _cloudBlobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(Filename(DirectoryName));
        if (!appendBlobReference.Exists())
        {
            appendBlobReference.CreateOrReplace();
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(events, ProcessEvent);
    }

    private static string Filename(string directoryName)
    {
        return $"{directoryName}/{DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}.log.txt";
    }

    private void ProcessEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
            {
                Layout.Format(streamWriter, loggingEvent);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            _cloudBlobContainer
                .GetAppendBlobReference(Filename(DirectoryName))
                .AppendBlock(memoryStream);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check for number of committed blocks before committing to the Blob using `_cloudBlobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(Filename(DirectoryName)).Properties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount` and make sure it is not more than 50000. I think you are hitting block count limitation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/append-block

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to implement this. Please add your answer below, if the fix works, I can reward you the bounty.

Comment: The solution works, thank you very much! Can you post the answer below? I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Append Block [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/append-block) you might be hittin 50,000 block limit for a blob. Make sure to check for number of committed blocks before committing to the Blob using:

```
var blockCount = _cloudBlobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(Filename(DirectoryName))
                                    .Properties
                                    .AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount;
```

and make sure it is not more than 50000.